# ideaIC-14.0.2.exe IntelliJ Setup Wizard fails without ever displaying

Tags: intellij-idea

1. I downloaded the community edition of IntelliJ as ideaIC-14.0.2.exe.
2. I ran ideaIC-14.0.2.exe with evelated rights on a Windows 7 64 laptop with the 32 bit version of Java 6 installed.
3. I notice that two copies of ideaIC-14.0.2.exe appears in task explorer when none were previously present.
4. Both tasks go away without the setup wizard ever appearing5. I saw nothing related in the Event log.

Do you know how I might be able to overcome this issue and install this app?

Comment: did you get an errors during install? I'd suggest you uninstall and re-install

Comment: I saw no visible outpout at all. No dialog boxes, no error message boxes, no log file of event log entries, no evidence of running at except for seeing it in the task manager for a minute before it goes away.

Comment: is your JAVA_HOME setup correctly? do you have any AntiVirus running that may be shutting it down?

Comment: JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk

I am brand new to Java, but I was able to get Spring Tool Set, Eclipse, Maven and Tomcat all working fine. I am compare the IDEs to see which one I land using.

As a noobie, I am just tryingt o do Hello World stuff

Comment: Hmmm, not typical JAVA_HOME but as long as you have a valid JDK under that directory, it should be ok.  Can you confirm you have a /bin and correct java JRE under that directory?  Also, where did you get the installer from?  Directly from jetbrains.com? (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) or somewhere else?  If you have Eclipse running, which JDK does it use? - btw, this is the first time I hear of someone having issues with the installer... so it seems weird...

Comment: Confirmed and yes, I did download the Community version from the Jetbrains site. Also, Eclipse is using the same JDK location. BTW, I installed Intellij on another machine (at home rather than here at work) with no issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69341/discussion-between-ochi-and-chadd).

Comment: Looks like your installer file may be corrupted. The size of the correct file is 200.111.392 bytes. How large is your download? Did you try redownloading the installer?

Comment: I tried downloading the file ideaIC-14.0.3.exe, getting a newer version. Explorer column display shows the size was 195,846 KB. When I do Properties I see size: 191 MB (200,545,408 bytes) and Size on Disk: 191 MB (200,548,352 bytes). I got the same result...nothing.

Comment: Is Windows Firewall enabled? Also, did you try to unblock your file(Properties->General->Unblock) and download it one more time?

Comment: See my answer which addresses your questions

Comment: have you tried running the installer from window command prompt? It's possible it's a group policy error (if it's your work machine), which might get output if you run it from the command prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the Firewall was previously suggested and tried.Usually, I run every setup program with elevated rights. I was told that I never need Admin rights to install. This time, I added myself to the Admin user group (which you would think shouldn't be possible!) and then ran setup after once again disabling my firewall. And this time, it worked! I suppose it's possible that I did not disable all of the firewall options last time, but I believe I did. If so, elevated rights must have been insufficient. I forgot to try unchecking the Unblock property on the file-that was a good suggestion, though.